# Webapi function without parameter and using HttpGet results in 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

A webapi function that uses `HttpGet` and does not have a parameter seems to not add the route. With this code

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Testing
{
  public class FooController: ApiController
  {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("foobar")]
    public FoobarOutput foobar()
    {
      return new FoobarOutput();
    }

    public class FoobarOutput
    {
      public int age;
      public string name;
    }
  }
}
```

surfing to `/foobar` results in 404 (webpage not found).

However, if I add an int parameter

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Testing
{
  public class FooController: ApiController
  {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("foobar/{id}")]
    public FoobarOutput foobar(int id)
    {
      return new FoobarOutput();
    }

    public class FoobarOutput
    {
      public int age;
      public string name;
    }
  }
}
```

I will be able to surf to `/foobar/34` (any integer will do).

Why do I have to add a parameter?

(The class `FoobarOutput` is used to collect the output values from the function).

## edit

I have managed to have a parameterless function called, so now I need to checkout why it was not working in the first place. I remove this question if I cannot find that out.

Comment: Show the controller definition as well along with any attributes used. Are you sure you have attribute routing enabled?

Comment: The question has been edited.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that attribute routing is enabled.

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And that the appropriate attributes are present on the contoller

```
[RoutePrefix("foobar")]
public class FooController: ApiController {

    //GET foobar
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult foobar() {
        FoobarOutput model = new FoobarOutput();
        //...
        return Ok(model);
    }

    //GET foobar/34
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult foobar(int id) {
        FoobarOutput model = new FoobarOutput();
        //...
        return Ok(model);
    }

}
```

Your original code was most likely using the default convention based route

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: Yes, I enable attribute routing, or the route `/foobar/34` would be unknown. I stay away from the "convention based routing".

Comment: I tried to use RoutePrefix and Route like you did and it worked (even without parameters). Then I tried to remove the RoutePrefix and put the route in Route and that also worked. So my question has been contradicted, I need to checkout what was different.

Comment: Also, `[Route("{id}")]` should suffice?

Comment: Read up on route constraints.

Comment: Is that the answer on my question?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints